# jQuery/JavaScript - Parse HTTP RSS feed to HTTPS RSS Feed, what steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rss

I will try to not strafe away so much.

Here is my issue:

I have a HTTPS safe website where I am developing web-applications. My latest task is to read RSS from a non-HTTPS safe site (it is HTTP) but still keep the HTTPS safe.

Basically these are the steps I'm thinking off having to do:

DummySite1 (HTTP): Here I read all the HTTP rss and parse it as text.
DummySite2 (HTTPS): Here I get all text from DummySite1.
And now I can get the rss feed from DummySite2 while maintaining HTTPS to the core site.

Are all these steps really needed?

**IF YES:** 
I managed to make DummySite1 fairly simple using gfeedfetcher.js (jQuery plugin).
How can I get DummySite2 to work and maintain HTTPS?

**IF NO** 
How should I think, is there any "easy" solutions to this?

Comment: i'm not sure if this is a client side issue , you have to read the RSS in HTTPS server (using something like a php file) and have jquery open your rss reader (php file that echos rss) using https

Comment: Our "community" which the feed lies within, is not HTTP. This is the problem.
But we want to read RSS onto our HTTPS site.